# How to transalte this SQL query in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I have and SQL query:

```
SELECT        dbo.Course.courseID, dbo.Course.cricosCode, dbo.Course.courseName,
              dbo.StudentPaymentPlan.totalAmount, SUM(dbo.StudentPaymentDetails.paidAmount) AS paidTotal
FROM          dbo.StudentPaymentDetails 
INNER JOIN    dbo.StudentPaymentPlan ON dbo.StudentPaymentDetails.paymentPlanID = dbo.StudentPaymentPlan.paymentPlanID
INNER JOIN    dbo.Application ON dbo.StudentPaymentPlan.applicationID = dbo.Application.ApplicationId 
INNER JOIN    dbo.Course ON dbo.Application.courseID = dbo.Course.courseID
GROUP BY      dbo.Course.courseID, dbo.StudentPaymentPlan.totalAmount, dbo.Course.cricosCode, dbo.Course.courseName
```

What is its equivalent in LINQ?

Comment: http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx

Comment: It might be better to reformulate your question to: How to do a JOIN with LINQ

Comment: Thank you very much. If I want to SUM TotalAmount on PaymentPlanID(One level higher) how to insert it to this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this freehand, so it may take some fiddling to get it to work right, but the overall idea should be correct.

In the future, MSDN often has great documentation, which is how I wrote this up. In particular, I used their articles on the [join clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) and the [group clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx). Good luck!

```
from detail in dbo.StudentPaymentDetails
join plan in dbo.StudentPaymentPlan on detail.paymentPlanID equals plan.paymentPlanId
join application in dbo.Application on plan.applicationID equals application.ApplicationID
join course in dbo.Course on application.courseID equals course.courseID
select new {CourseID = course.courseID, CricosCode = course.cricosCode, CourseName = course.courseName, TotalAmount = plan.totalAmount, PaidTotal = detail.paidAmount.Sum()}
group entry by (entry.CourseID, entry.TotalAmount, entry.CricosCode, entry.CourseName)
```

Comment: If you're using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework you don't need to write any of this all you need is to write is `group x by y` and then `.Sum`